# Process an event using EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY doesn't work

Tags: c++, events, controls, wxwidgets

A header file:

```
class ttFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:
        ttFrame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title);
        ~ttFrame();
    private:
        enum
        {
            idMenuQuit = 1000,
            idMenuAbout,
            collapsible_key
        };
        void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);
        void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnEvent(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnSpinEvent(wxSpinEvent& event);
        wxCollapsiblePane *collpane;
        void OnEventCollapsible(wxNavigationKeyEvent& event);
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

A main function:

```
wxBoxSizer *sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

collpane = new wxCollapsiblePane(this, collapsible_key, "Collapsible pane:", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400,400), wxCP_NO_TLW_RESIZE);
sizer->Add(collpane);

    wxWindow *win = collpane->GetPane();
    wxSizer *paneSz = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    paneSz->Add(new wxStaticText(win, wxID_ANY, "test!"), 1, wxGROW|wxALL, 2);

    win->SetSizer(paneSz);
    paneSz->SetSizeHints(win);

SetSizer(sizer);
```

Event declaration:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ttFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY(ttFrame::OnEventCollapsible)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Event function emitter:

```
void ttFrame::OnEventCollapsible(wxNavigationKeyEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Not event trigger on key TAB");
}
```

When I click TAB key or some function key it will not trigger an event. Other event such as EVT_COLLAPSIBLEPANE_CHANGED(id, func): works.

In a documentation says

> EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY(func): Process a navigation key event.

An event won't trigger to show a wxMessageBox().

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `wxFrame` doesn't emit `wxNavigationKeyEvent`. The standard way to get `TAB` navigation is to add a `wxPanel` as the only child of the `wxFrame` and then add all your controls as children of the `wxPanel`. Docs [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_panel.html).

UPDATE: I was wrong, I've just verified that `wxFrame` *does* actually emit that event as well. What's different from a `wxPanel` is that there's no default navigation handler - unless you do it yourself, `TAB` won't navigate between controls when they're added directly to a `wxFrame`.

In your case, however, you also have another `wxPanel` in there - the one contained in the `wxCollapsiblePane`. You need to bind an event handler to that panel as well (`collpane->GetPane()->Bind(/*...*/)`) to catch its events too.

Between these two handlers, you should catch all relevant navigation events in your case.

UPDATE 2: `wxCollapsiblePane` implements navigation too, so binding a handler to it as well will catch additional events when focus switches from outside the pane to its contained `wxPanel` and back. Not sure how this could be useful though. If there are at least two controls added to the internal panel of the `wxCollapsiblePane`, in order to catch navigation events between them, you'll still need the handler bound to `collpane->GetPane()`.

Comment: No, i've tried but this didn't work. It should be bind with main frame window to trigger on key event. But here is some interesting sample but I've not idea how to implement in this scenario. Here is from filezilla sample file and inside event handler you have event key constructor: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/filezilla/src/interface/Mainfrm.cpp#OnMenuHandler In a code `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ttFrame, wxFrame)` should receive event key handler such as `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ttFrame, wxFrame, eventkey)`

Comment: What did you try exactly and didn't work? Did you derive a class from `wxPanel`, set up an event table for *that class*, containing the handler for `wxNavigationKeyEvent`, and it didn't fire?

Comment: Exactly, it will not fire an event wit wxPanel derived from class and added an event. I'm trying now just like this: `collpane->Connect(wxEVT_NAVIGATION_KEY, wxNavigationKeyEvent(ttFrame::OnEventCollapsible), NULL, this);`

Comment: No, don't bind the event handler to the collapsible pane, bind it to the collapsible pane's internal `wxPanel`, the one you get from `collpane->GetPane()`. When a control inside that pane has focus, then it's that panel that generates the navigation events.

Comment: Basically, in your case, you have *two* `wxPanel`s: the one your class is derived from, and the internal one from `wxCollapsiblePane`. In order to catch all navigation events, you'll need to bind handlers to both these panels. The collapsible pane complicates things a bit here; you could try starting with a simpler case, just one `wxTextCtrl` inside the main `wxPanel`, see that it works, then work up from there.